# Civ: Beyond Earth Pitboss?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I picked up Beyond Earth from a Humble Bundle and wanted to know if there was a Pitboss for it. It doesn't look like there is (yet?) from what I've found so far, but looking for a more current answer.

Comment: ...Pitboss?  I am not familiar with the term.

Comment: @Frank Civ V (and I think Civ IV, but I could be wrong) had a multiplayer option called Pitboss, where one player could leave the game running as a kind of "host" and players could check in and take their turns whenever they wanted, permitting asynchronous play (read:  players don't all have to be online at the same time).  I'd have really liked that option if it were easier to use, but having to leave Civ V running all the time on my old machine wasn't a real option, and I had no luck changing a game in progress into a Pitboss format game, so when we realized we wanted it, we couldn't use it.

Comment: @gatherer818 In Civ IV, Firaxis built a standalone program to run the Pitboss, so you didn't need a copy of the game left running. Given the trajectory they've been heading on with Pitboss since then I fully expect there to be no option in Beyond Earth.

Comment: Giant Multiplayer Robot was developing this but I don't know if they ever actually did.